# GWT Window.ClosingEvent setMessage is not working in FF browser

Tags: gwt

I could able to override the default message(**setMessage**) in IE, but it is not working in FireFox

```
         Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onWindowClosing(final Window.ClosingEvent closingEvent) {

          //Working in IE, but not in FF
     closingEvent.setMessage(mailingAddressExtractionMessages.mailingAddressExtraction_unsavedDataAlertMessage());

        }
    });
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "is not working"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - I could able to customize this message by calling setMessage() in IE. But it is not reflecting in FF.